# From interpeted to native code: "dynamic" languages compiler support

Tags: python, perl, programming-languages

First, I am aware that dynamic languages is a term used mainly by a vendor; I am using it just to have a container word to include languages like Perl (a favorite of mine), Python, Tcl, Ruby, PHP and so on. They are interpreted but I am interested here to refer to languages featuring strong capability to support the programmer efficiency and the support for typical constructs of modern interpreted languages

My question is: there are dynamic languages can be compiled efficiently in native executable code - typically for Windows platforms? Which ones? Maybe using some third part ad-hoc tools? I am not talking about huge executables carrying with them a full interpreter or some similar tricks nor some smart module able to include its own dependances or some required modules, but a honest, straight, standard, solid executable code.

If not, there is some technical reason inhibiting the availability of such a best-of-both-world feature?

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're operating under a misunderstanding: These executables aren't huge because they just lump the interpreter in there, they're huge because the whole *runtime* is in there.

On Windows, most of your runtime is already installed, so you don't have to ship it. You *think* your program is small, but a quick look at the virtual memory mappings will tell you that even a small "hello-world" type program written in C is a couple megabytes big.

That's just how big useful runtimes are.

If you *really* want to keep your ship-size small, your only choice is to use the runtimes that are already there, and *that* means C/C++ and (recently) dot-net.

If you *really* can't swallow the runtime, Forth is as small as it gets.

The best, most aggressive dynamic languages with the best compilers for Windows are the commercial Lisps. They do a lot of inlining and pruning when producing executables, so you end up shipping only what you use. They are still 1.5x to 5x larger than C/C++ programs.

As far as languages that you know: Perl is as fat as they get. ActiveState has [perlapp](http://docs.activestate.com/pdk/6.0/PerlApp.html) which I'm sure you're already aware of, but you dismissed because of it's size. Revisit it if you can.

Now, to answer your question *(is) there is some technical reason inhibiting the availability of such a best-of-both-world feature?*: **Yes**.

Perl cannot be statically analyzed ([proof](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663393)), which means there's no way for a perl compiler to tell what can be discarded. That means *every* part of Perl's runtime needs to be available to your program becuase there's no way for your program to indicate what parts can be discarded.

*That* means that getting a smaller executable is equivalent to getting a smaller runtime, and you should be comfortable accepting that if the perl developers knew how to make the perl runtime smaller without discarding any features, they'd probably do it.

If you are willing to write in a strict subset of Python or PHP, *these* languages can be analyzed. [Shed Skin](http://shed-skin.blogspot.com/) and [HipHop-php](http://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php) are pretty good, but they're still quite large, and they don't support all of Pythons and PHP's features which means that some modules will simply not work. To my knowledge, nobody has implemented pruning for either of these languages (most of the focus in these compilers is in improving their lackluster performance) and it may be another decade or more before anyone bothers, however *these still will be* the restrictions you have to accept when doing this sort of thing.

Comment: There are two options for slimmed down perl.  You can target `miniperl` or `microperl` if you want a subset of Perl with a smaller executable.  `miniperl` is built as part of the perl build process, and can do anything perl does, except use dynamically loaded libraries (i.e. no XS modules).  `microperl` sacrifices interfaces to the OS, so functions like `crypt` that are system specific may not work.  I haven't seen a `PAR::Packer` type program that uses either of these though.  Both of these trimmed perls can be built from the standard perl source distro.

Comment: And there are other ways to compile Perl to native code: the [RPerl](https://github.com/wbraswell/rperl) compiler translates a subset of Perl to C++, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The [PyPy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/) project does what you describe for a fairly complete subset of Python.

In the general case, this is a very hard problem to solve, largely due to the very attributes that make these languages "dynamic": late binding, weakly-typed variables, data structures and containers, `eval` facilities, a fuzzy divide between programming and meta-programming, etc. But a lot of effort is being poured into it, such as the JavaScript JIT-compiler projects listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_engines#New_generation_JavaScript_engines_for_web_browsers.2C_all_implementing_just-in-time_compilation_.28JIT.29_or_variations_of_that_idea:).

Answer (score 1):

[Shed Skin](http://shed-skin.blogspot.com/) is an experimental (and restricted) Python-to-C++ compiler that can do what you describe. As Marcelo indicates above with PyPy, there are limitations on what you can compile with Shed Skin, but if you are willing to accept the restrictions, you can achieve large speedups.